# Convert event function to observavle that emits data every second

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following function which emits data while the torrent is downloading:

```
torrentBuffer.on('download', () => {
      
})
```

This function triggers events really quickly and I would just need the data maybe once every second to update my data.

How could I achieve this with rxjs observable?

Comment: You can use https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `fromEvent` and `bufferTime`

```
fromEvent(torrentBuffer, 'download').pipe(
    takeUntil(fromEvent(torrentBuffer, 'done')),
    bufferTime(1000)
).subscribe(event => ...)
```

See:

1. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent
2. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffertime

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: How do I make this stop emitting after the value is the same? After it stops downloading it still emits the same value every second?

Comment: Do you have a torrentBuffer 'complete' event?

Comment: Try adding `takeUntil(fromEvent(torrentBuffer, 'done'))` before the `bufferTime(1000)` line